# Jquery / Javascript: There is a NaN on my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing an HTML loop using javascript. It will loop through a series of images and display them with additional information. It appears that there is always a NaN showing on the HTML output as shown here.[image]

Here is the javascript in question:

```
var caption = '<p></p>';
if($.isEmptyObject(data[i].caption) !== true)
{
    caption = '<p class="caption" style="top:'+data[i].height+'px;">'+
            data[i].caption +
          '</p>';
}
var li = '<li data-uk-modal="{target:#modal-open-image}"'
        + 'class="open"'
        + 'image="'+ data[i].photo +'"'
            + 'caption_height="'+ data[i].height +'"'
        + 'caption="'+ data[i].caption +'">'
        + '<a href="#" class="uk-thumbnail uk-overlay-toggle">'
        + '<div class="uk-overlay">'
        + '<img src="'+ data[i].photo +'" width="250px"/>'
        + caption +
        + '<div class="uk-overlay-caption">'
        + '<p> Sender: ' + data[i].sender + '</p>'
            + '<p> Date: ' + data[i].date + '</p>'
            + '<p> limit: '+ data[i].limit + '</p>'
        + '<p> counter: ' + data[i].counter + '</p>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</a>'
        +'</li>';
        $photo.append(li);
```

[image]

I would think the problem would lie on the caption variable. the data[i] is an array of from a database query.

[image]

I need to check if there is something on the data[i].caption. I tried using length, but that doesn't work, so I check if the object exist. Though I am not sure if that works.

My question, is how to display properly check if the caption is empty, and if none it will not add anything on the var li.

Thanks.

Comment: It's clear, Vladimir Putin is just Not a Number.

Comment: Try this `[...] + ""+caption + [...]`

Comment: Pretty sure it means "Not a Nationalist"

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán Nothing happened.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Please use this one jQuery.isEmptyObject(); like :: jQuery.isEmptyObject(data[i].photo);

Comment: @kuldeepraj did this: if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(data[i].caption) !== true) ... nothing.

Comment: @MrA Please provide me full code url then I will find the problem by console .

Comment: @kuldeepraj what do you mean by full-code url?

Comment: Please @MrA do by this isNaN fucntion if isNaN(caption)==true

Comment: full code mean did you upload this code in any location ?

Comment: @MrA try this: `+ String(caption) +`

Answer (score 0):

You can code it in one line:

```
( (data && data[i] && data[i].caption) ? " your stuff " : "")
```

But pay attention that checking 'data[i].caption' in javascript means that: zero is false, empty string is false.
Furthermore if you referring a number you can add a condition using the method [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one in place of the '+ caption +'

```
isNaN(data[i].caption) ? '' : data[i].caption 

or if(isNaN(data[i].caption)==true){

  //do somthing
}else{

 //do somthing

}
```

Comment: just to clafiry, I should be condition caption variable, not data[i].caption ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback. I manage to gobble up the solutions you game me and I ended up with this.

```
var height = (data[i].height == null)?0:data[i].height;
var caption= (data[i].caption== null)?'':data[i].caption;   
var li = '<li data-uk-modal="{target:\'#modal-open-image\'}"'
        + 'class="open"'
        + 'image="'+ data[i].photo +'"'
        + 'caption_height="'+ height +'"'
        + 'caption="'+ caption +'">'
        + '<a href="#" class="uk-thumbnail uk-overlay-toggle">'
        + '<div class="uk-overlay">'
        + '<img src="'+ data[i].photo +'" width="250px"/>'
        + '<p class="caption" style="top:' + height +'px;">'
        + caption
        + '</p>'
        + '<div class="uk-thumbnail-caption">'
        + '<p> Sender: ' + data[i].sender + '</p>'
        + '<p> Reciever: '+ data[i].reciever + '</p>'
        + '<p> Date: ' + data[i].date + '</p>'
        + '<p> limit: '+ data[i].limit + '</p>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</a>'
        +'</li>';
```